# Custom post_per_page not working in categories in Wordpress and Woocommerce

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, pagination, woocommerce

I have an online shop which display all products in the shop page.

I use the following code in functions.php:

```
//EDIT POSTS PER PAGE IN SHOP

add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', create_function( '$cols', 'return -1;' ));
```

When I'm in the [main shop page](https://openwallsgallery.com/artworks) this works without a problem.

But when I'm in a [category page](https://openwallsgallery.com/artwork/original/), the limit seems to set at 100 and it shows pagination.
I don't know where it comes from (in Settings/Reading it's set at 200), or how to change it.

Weirdly enough, if I use the AJAX filters in the category page, when I go back to displaying all, it will show all products without pagination, but on page reload it will show the pagination.

Any tips on how to display all products and get rid of the pagination directly on page load?

Comment: Hey Eric, are you using a theme?  Is it possible there is a setting in the theme specific to the categories that is taking priority over your custom code?

Comment: I'm using a theme but created by me... Is all very weird, I'd understand that the categories would display as many posts as set in Settings/Reading, ignoring my functions.php, but it doesn't, it just shows 100...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code, it is removing pagination and you can apply further condition inside function too.

```
function no_nopaging($query) {
     if ($query->is_archive()) {
        $query->set('nopaging', 1);
      }
 }

add_action('parse_query', 'no_nopaging');
```

Comment: All! I can define the number (e.g. 500) or just put -1 and it will display all products.

Comment: Yes, it used to be 500 : )

Comment: How would we know this code has already been tried? It isn't posted in the original question? Please consider editing your question to elaborate all the things you have tried so we can check your work and avoid duplicating your efforts. PS- @Ash Patel be careful, this will apply to ALL archives and not just the WooCommerce archives.